# React not loading any component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

**Problem:**
When running my react application locally with "npm run" I get a white page with no error logs.

**Frameworks/programs used**

- React 15.6.2
- NodeJs 8.11.3
- webpack 1.15.0
- babel 6.26.0
- Git 2.18

**OS**
Windows 10

I tried deleting all the node modules and the package-lock.json, I also tried updating the version of webpack as sugested here [Whitescreen of death after pulling from git repo (ReactJS, Nginx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189205/whitescreen-of-death-after-pulling-from-git-repo-reactjs-nginx)

One thing I noticed is that while I don't see any thing been loaded if I change a component I get the message:
    "The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (full reload needed)"

I tried updating the hot loader but this didn't work either, does anyone have an idea of whats going on?

**UPDATE**
Here is the webpack sever configuration:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const webpackAliases = require('./webpackAliases');
const localBasePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');
const { localModuleResolve, localRootResolve, resolve } = require('../../common/tools');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const {
  babelLoader,
  jsonLoader,
  urlLoader,
  svgReactLoader,
  extractStylesLoader,
  faviconLoader,
  declarityLoader,
  workerLoader
} = require('./webpackLoaders');

module.exports = (basePath, appEntry, devConfig) => {
  const routesEntry = devConfig.app.routes;
  const historyAlias = {
    'deps-history': typeof devConfig.devServer.history == 'string'
                        ? devConfig.devServer.history
                        : localRootResolve('common/defaultHistory')
  }

  const extraWebpackConfig = devConfig.webpack || {};
  const extraAliases = extraWebpackConfig.aliases || {};

  return {
    entry: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      resolve('react-hot-loader/patch'),
      resolve('webpack-hot-middleware/client'),
      localRootResolve('src/devEntry.js')
    ],
    output : {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: extraWebpackConfig.destinationPath || path.resolve(basePath, 'lib'),
      publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        babelLoader({
          use: {
            options: {
              plugins: require("react-hot-loader/babel")
            }
          },
          include: [
            localRootResolve('src'),
            localRootResolve('lib'),
            path.join(basePath, 'src')
          ],
        }),
        jsonLoader(),
        urlLoader(),
        svgReactLoader(),
        faviconLoader(),
        declarityLoader(),
        workerLoader()
      //  extractStylesLoader()
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: Object.assign(
        {},
        webpackAliases,
        extraAliases,
        historyAlias,
        routesEntry ? {'deps-routes': path.resolve(basePath, routesEntry)} : {}
      ),
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".dsx"],
      modules: [path.resolve(basePath, 'node_modules'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../../', 'node_modules')]
    },
    externals: {
      'react/addons': 'react',
      'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': 'react',
      'react/lib/ReactContext': 'react',
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'WORKING_DIR']),
      //new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name]-styles.css', allChunks: true }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: function (module) {
          // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
          return module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1;
        }
      }),
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: show how you are serving your bundles or how you are running webpack dev server, and also your webpack config

Comment: Add following code in your entry.js

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}

Comment: I'm already doing entry.js if (module.hot) { module.hot.accept(); }

Comment: @PlayMa256 I added the webpack server configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing we were able to fix the problem and it was related to permissions, it was strange that the hod-loader module was not able to update any of the files so we  thought it had to be related to file/folder permissions. When I initially cloned the repo I was doing everything with elevated permissions even when running Git Bash, we decided to re-clone the repo in another folder and ran gitbash without elevated permissions, after that everything is working fine. Notice that I tried re-cloning the repo before and it didn't work because I was doing everything with elevated permissions, I don't know why this is the case or if it had to do with the existing IT policies but hope this can help someone else with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and mount your components with that setup and see if they work. It's a lot easier and allows you to test your app without too much configuration.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

after that

```
create-react-app your-app-name
```

Then you can test every component without webpack configuration and try to find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Hot Module Replacement -> It's like LiveReload for every module.

---

Adding `module.hot.accept()` means you're telling webpack the module can handle being hot reloading, but not actually doing anything.

---

Another option would be to include `react-hot-loader` or `babel-plugin-react-transform` in your project.

---

***There is an official middleware to help you with this:*** [webpack-hot-middleware](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware)

---

**npm install --save-dev webpack-hot-middleware**

***Next, enable hot reloading in your webpack config:***

*Add the following plugins to the plugins array:*

```
plugins: [
    // OccurenceOrderPlugin is needed for webpack 1.x only
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Use NoErrorsPlugin for webpack 1.x
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
]
```

Occurrence ensures consistent build hashes, hot module replacement is somewhat self-explanatory, no errors are used to handle errors more cleanly.

Add 'webpack-hot-middleware/client' into the entry array. This connects to the server to receive notifications when the bundle rebuilds and then updates your client bundle accordingly.**

***Now add the middleware into your server:***

```
***Add webpack-dev-middleware the usual way:***

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
    noInfo: true, publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
}));
Add webpack-hot-middleware attached to the same compiler instance

app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));
And you're all set!
```

---

**References: [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/)**

Comment: I tried adding the configuration mentioned in the plugins, I was also already using  the middleware